# Why I loose a src of iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs, casperjs

There is an iframe in html:

```
<iframe id="iframeViewer3D" width="340" height="210" scrolling="no" src="/global/viewer.aspx?mode=3DWebGL&amp;xmp=-1-59-flexible_shaft_coupling_c172903000300.xmp&amp;previewCad=flexible_shaft_coupling_c172903000300&amp;h=210&amp;w=340&amp;version=3&amp;Lang=en&amp;fwsid=3DCC&amp;CF=0&amp;PMLOG=1&amp;DisplayMode=small&amp;manId=ACCES"></iframe>
```

And when I try to get a HTML of this iframe with casperjs:

```
var link = casper.getHTML('#iframeViewer3D', true);
```

it returns a part of html without src:

```
<iframe id=\"iframeViewer3D\" width=\"340\" height=\"210\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe>
```

Why src is lost and how to get this src? I guess this happens because link leeds to anoteher domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it with getting the src-value directly?

```
var link = casper.getElementAttribute('#iframeViewer3D', 'src');
```

Comment: Thanks, but my aim is simply get iframe-tag with src, no navigate "into" the iframe.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the "src" is loaded a bit later. try it with a wait before you save it. This should be safe: casper.waitForSelector('#iframeViewer3D[src]')

Comment: Now it returns an error "Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting."

Comment: Then the source (src) is not loaded in phantomjs, but would be just a guessing why. you can try to look if the iframe is loaded by searching for elements in the iframe or taking a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did as you advised in first post: var link = casper.getElementAttribute('#PartnerFrame', 'src');, but for another parent iframe, and  recieved a fit result.